# jquery to find all exact td matches

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#servertable td:eq(' + server + ')')
```

this finds only 1 (first I think) match, how to find all matches. 
btw. td:contains will not work for me.

Comment: Can you show a bit of the HTML markup? Are you sure it's only finding one match? How do you know? Are you checking how many elements are returned in the collection, or are you doing something to highlight the results? A bit more code would help.

Comment: You are doing eq, which can only possible match one element, since it selects it by index. It is the equivalent of using $('#servertable td').eq(#) or $('#servertable td')[#]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`eq` expects a numerical index to only return a single row. If you want to match a td by its contents, you have to use the [:contains](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains#text) selector. Saying "it doesn't work" and throwing it away is not the right approach to the problem, as the selector is (most likely) not at fault (Do note its case sensitive, which might be it...)

Anyhow, if you have a table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>World</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>World</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $("td:contains('Hello')").css('color','red');
});
```

Will turn all cells with "Hello" to red. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/uzoxi).

If you need a case insensitive match, you could do this, using the [`filter`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter) function:

```
$(function() {
    var search = 'HELLO'.toLowerCase();
    $("td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1;
    }).css('color','red');
});
```

If you need to match the *exact* contents of the cell, you could use something similar to the above:

```
$(function() {
    var search = 'HELLO'.toLowerCase();
    $("td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase() == search;
    }).css('color','red');
});
```

The above is case insensitive (by turning both the search and the contents to lower case when comparing) otherwise you can just remove those if you want case sensitivity. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ofeca).

Comment: ok, so what if you have in your table: <td>Hello buddy</td> ?
What's going to happen is "Hello buddy" will turn red as well, but what if you only wanted to turn "Hello" by itself, exact match.

Comment: To add to the answer: Since you only need the content of the tag, you don't have to wrap _this_, you can use `return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == search`

Comment: @ra170 The containsExact extension that I added below will solve your test case of finding only the exact string of "Hello" and not "Hello buddy"

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but the [:eq positional selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/eq) takes an integer *n* an finds the *nth* matching element.

So if you said td:eq(1) -- you'd get the 2nd TD element in the table (second because the first index is zero/0).

My guess is that you don't want to use the [:contains selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains) because you're looking for an exact string match and don't want partial matches.

I'm not aware that jquery has a built in selector that will meet your needs (if so, please correct me).  You could add one as an extension or use another method, such as an attribute selector to do the search for you.

If you are able to control the generated HTML, you could add an ID attribute to each TD like so:

```
   <table id="servertable" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Server</th><th>Memory</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td id="server_mars">Mars</td><td>4 GB</td></tr>
            <tr><td id="server_venus">Venus</td><td>1 GB</td></tr>
            <tr><td id="server_jupiter">Jupiter</td><td>2 GB</td></tr>
            <tr><td id="server_uranus">Uranus</td><td>8 GB</td></tr>
            <tr><td id="server_mars_2010">Mars_2010</td><td>4 GB</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <form>
        <label for="server">Find:</label><input type="text" id="server" />
        <button id="find">Find</button>
    </form>
```

The following attribute selector would locate the correct TD in the table:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#find").click(function() {
            var server = $("#server").val();
            $("#servertable td").css("background-color", "");  // reset 
            $("#servertable td[id='server_" + server.toLowerCase() + "']").css("background-color", "#FFFF00");  
            return false;
        });
    });
   </script>
```

If you instead want to target the entire row that has the TD that you're looking for, you can add additional selectors:

```
      $("#servertable tbody tr").css("background-color", "");
      $("#servertable tbody tr:has(td[id='server_" + server.toLowerCase() + "'])").css("background-color", "#FFFF00");
```

The tbody tag isn't completely necessary, it just helps to distinguish between rows in the table body and rows in the table header.

Answer (score 1):

Try :containsExact

http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2010/05/jquery-selectors-adding-contains-exact.html

```
    $.extend( $.expr[":"], {
 containsExact: $.expr.createPseudo ?
  $.expr.createPseudo(function(text) {
   return function(elem) {
    return $.trim(elem.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) === text.toLowerCase();
   };
  }) :
  // support: jQuery <1.8
  function(elem, i, match) {
   return $.trim(elem.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) === match[3].toLowerCase();
  },

 containsExactCase: $.expr.createPseudo ?
  $.expr.createPseudo(function(text) {
   return function(elem) {
    return $.trim(elem.innerHTML) === text;
   };
  }) :
  // support: jQuery <1.8
  function(elem, i, match) {
   return $.trim(elem.innerHTML) === match[3];
  },

 containsRegex: $.expr.createPseudo ?
  $.expr.createPseudo(function(text) {
   var reg = /^\/((?:\\\/|[^\/]) )\/([mig]{0,3})$/.exec(text);
   return function(elem) {
    return RegExp(reg[1], reg[2]).test($.trim(elem.innerHTML));
   };
  }) :
  // support: jQuery <1.8
  function(elem, i, match) {
   var reg = /^\/((?:\\\/|[^\/]) )\/([mig]{0,3})$/.exec(match[3]);
   return RegExp(reg[1], reg[2]).test($.trim(elem.innerHTML));
  }

});
```

Comment: Your answer contains a link from my answer and basically nothing else. Nice summary. :)

Comment: @TimoLehto just noticed your comment from years ago.  didn't just copy your answer, didn't even notice your link.  Added the code example to my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#servertable td')
```

will find all td elements, but it's not entirely clear what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered this very same problem as the original author. As Paulo the original question poser had. Which selector can I use to match elements based equality check on element contents. At least I presume that's what he did (as did I) try to achieve and that would also explain why he (as well as I) can't use contains for the obvious reasons ra170 pointed out in his comment. Anyhow if someone happens to stumble here looking for the answer to that question here's the short answer to it:

jQuery has no such matcher by default. The solution is to define your own matcher. To tackle the problem at hand see this excellent blog [post](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2010/05/jquery-selectors-adding-contains-exact.html) by Motte.