# jQuery selector td with specific text

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery selector which looks like this:

```
$("#MasterListDVWP tr td:contains('" + currentSchool + "')").siblings("td:contains('Yes')").siblings("td:contains('CD'),td:contains('Other1')").each(function() {
// do something
});
```

Could someone help me to convert the selector so that it returns the object that matches the exact text rather than just contains? 
I know this isn't valid but something like this..siblings("td:equals('CD')")...

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921940/jquery-to-find-all-exact-td-matches

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your best bet is probably the .filter() function. Pass it a function that tests the text of the elements you're checking

```
$('#MasterListDVWP tr td').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() === currentSchool;
}).siblings('td').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() === 'CD' || $(this).text() === 'Other1';
}).each(function(){
  // do something
});
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no jQuery selector like that, but you could create one:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    containsExactly: function (obj, index, meta, stack) {
        if ($(obj).text() === meta[3]) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you do that, then you can now do:

```
$("#MasterListDVWP tr td:td:containsExactly('" + currentSchool + "')").siblings("td:containsExactly('Yes')").siblings("td:td:containsExactly('CD'),td:td:containsExactly('Other1')").each(function() {
// do something
});
```

[**Try it out!**](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/ZcGBT/)

Comment: Maybe a far stretch for simple string matching and OP's request, but I upvoted you because of the pro tip, so interesting, and it can be really expanded to make complex selectors.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible with bare selectors.

Maybe you can use `.filter()` like:

```
 $(...selectors...).filter(
     function (index) { return $(this).text() == "textToMatch"; }
);
```

For multiple filterings on the same element:

```
 $(...selectors...).filter(
     function (index) { 
          return $(this).text() == "textToMatch" && $(this).text()=="anotherText"; 
     }
);
```

or just chain various `.filter()` declarations together.

Use || (or) instead of && to find TD's with a text *or* another.

Comment: @PremShrestha Obviously you can chain various `filter()` to make multiple filterings

Comment: I get that, but this will filter only one, I need a selector which will first filter by one text and then by other and other etc...

Comment: @PremShrestha Just like I just said: you can **chain** various `.filter ()` like `$(...selectors...).filter(
     function () { return $(this).text() == "textToMatch"; }
).filter(
     function () { return $(this).text() == "anothertextToMatch"; }
).filter(...)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering rows TD's with a text

```
$("#table_id tr td").filter(
     function (index) { return $(this).text() == text_to_find; }
).parent().show()
```