# How do I remove an option from select list JQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My list can not have an option value like

```
<option value="some_value"> Some text</option>
```

My current code is

```
<select id="select1">   
     <option>One</option>   
     <option>Two</option>   
     <option>Three</option>   
</select>
<script src=   
"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">   
</script>
<script>
$("option[value='Three']").remove()
</script>
```

I can not find a way to remove an option from a list if the option does not have a value.

I tried removing it with JQuery but it didn't work well.

Thanks

Comment: *if the option does not have a value* - how would you determine which option to remove?  The 3rd one? 2nd?  By its text?   [Your code](https://jsfiddle.net/23eodfcg/) removes by value, any other code will need to remove by X - depending on what X is determines what the code is.  eg to remove by [text](https://jsfiddle.net/23eodfcg/1/):  `$("option:contains(Three)").remove()`

Comment: @freedomn-m but is there an option where it is not contains but the string must be exactly the thing?

Comment: Also: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5940232/2181514)

Comment: @freedomn-m It doesn't work

Comment: @freedomn-m also if the select just uses name=something instead of id=something how do I make the code only work on that one list? is it like.                   
$("#listname option:contains(one)").remove()?

Comment: jquery uses same rules as css.  https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/#refining-amp-filtering-selections   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final code

```html
<select id="select1">   
     <option>One</option>   
     <option>Two</option>   
     <option>Three</option>   
</select>
<script src=   
"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">   
</script>
<script>
$("option:contains(Three)").remove()
</script>
```

It works and it is a efficient code

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `:contains()`

```
$("option:contains('Three')").remove()
```

https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

you can use loop on all `#select1 option`

to be able to write an if condition to determine if option should be deleted or not

```
$("#select1 option").each((index, option) => {
  if({your condition}) {
    $(option).remove();
  }
});
```

```js
$("#select1 option").each((index, option) => {
  if($(option).text() === 'Three') {
    $(option).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="select1">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id property to each option tag, then just select this id.
if you need it to work dynamically you can construct some letters with an index number, eg. `opt-1, opt-2 ....`

Answer (score 0):

Select the option from select which needs to remove. Use jQuery `remove()` method to remove the option from the HTML document.

```
 $("option:contains('Three')").remove()
```

Comment: It doesn't work because the option does not have a value